Cant find default Sharepoint Page Library in Graph API Call / How to get columns of pages
I am trying to get the content of the custom columns of our Sharepoint page library. For document libraries I can get these values using expand with fields, which does not seem to be possible with pages.
Unfortunately, I can't find this content when using
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/pages/{page-id}. Also, when trying to list all libraries via https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists, I only get document libraries, not the page library.
Is there any way to get the content of columns for pages via Graph API or is this feature not implemented yet? If not, is there a way in the Sharepoint API?
